# Attach valgrind with daemon and collect logs for each daemon call

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind, daemon, memory-leak-detector

I have a client server system, completely written in c++. server runs as `/etc/init.d/serverd` with start/stop options. `Client.exe` executes any command as `client.exe --options`. With each client call, daemon hits.
I want to attach `valgrind` with `/etc/init.d/serverd` to detect leak.
I tried below options but failed.

```
/usr/local/bin/valgrind --log-file=valgrind_1.log -v --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full --tool=memcheck --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 /etc/init.d/ serverd start
```

Each time it fails to attached with daemon.

What we want is to attach `valgrind` with daemon **at starting time** `[ the exact point is , I will stop daemon , attach valgrind with it and then start it again ]` so that each time , execution of `client.exe --options`, logs should be generated for daemon in `--log-file=valgrind_1.log`

Does anyone have any idea about how to do the same?

Comment: How does the run scrip look like for `serverd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems not possible to attach valgrind to an existing process:
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.attach

It seems to me the best practice is to kill the daemon process, and run by yourself the executable in valgrind.

Comment: I did the same but not able to attach `valgrind` with daemon properly. Initial logs are there till daemon get started but after that, logs for each daemon hit by `client.exe`, there are no logs in log file, given by option `--log-file=valgrind_1.log`. It means daemon is running and working properly but valgrind is not able to generate logs and unable to analyse memory leak of daemon.

Comment: So I don't know the answer.. I allow myself naive comments: 1. Are you sure valgrind is running in this case? `ps -e | grep valgrind` should indicate that. 2. Are you sure that you are searching the log at the right place? Maybe defining it in an absolute file is safer.

Comment: @PrashantSingh  you might have to add --trace-children=yes to the valgrind args, if your daemon is e.g. forking and then execing.  And if the above starts several processes under valgrind, you better make the log file 'unique' using e.g. the %p marker in the --log-file arg to have the pid part of the log filename.

Comment: I find that's not applicable when you need to debug a process in a docker container

Answer (score 1):

For systemd managed daemon, you can change the `ExecStart=` to run valgrind like following:

> ExecStart={valgrind-command-with-flags} /usr/sbin/foo-daemon

Do make sure to redirect the output to a well defined location.

***Caution***: Daemon running with valgrind could be extremely slow and could potentially not run as expected